# "A dual nationality" vs. "dual nationalities"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, nouns, articles

Which one is correct?

> 1. He has a dual nationality.
> 2. He has dual nationality.
> 3. He has dual nationalities.

Comment: I used have dual citizenship. Extrapolate as you feel fit. :-)

Comment: The vast majority of Americans (for instance) have dual nationality. Unless you are referring to ethnicity, `dual citizenship` is probably more appropriate, and less ambiguous.

Comment: @horatio: How is nationality different from citizenship? Is the first one just not official or not recognized by a government?

Comment: Note that I said "nationality" is often *ambiguous*, but not wrong. It is common at some point for someone to enquire as to one's nationality. For example, by parents are by turns Irish, English, and German. I have friends who claim to be of 5 or six different nationalities. So in my personal experience, nationality does not always mean citizenship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My vote is for "He has dual nationality."  This construction treats "dual nationality" as a legal status unto itself, not as countable item(s).

The Google test agrees with this, returning 9,000, 68,000, and 3,000 results for your three respective options.

Comment: Did you google the sentence using "He has"?

Answer (score 1):

I would say it was "dual nationality", cause although he has two types of nationality, he has one actual nationality, that is a mix of the two.

This can also be seen in things like "the dual number.", which is a number composed of two other numbers.

Comment: I think you will find dual number more commonly refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_%28grammatical_number%29, than to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DualNumber.html, thought I agree - plural would refer to multiple things that can be called dual.